# Unable to Deploy Cloud Functions - Permission denied to enable service [artifactregistry.googleapis.com]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to deploy the default test function to check that everything works.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

But when I run `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only functions`, I get the following error:

```js
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
!  artifactregistry: missing required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com. Enabling now...
Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to enable service [artifactregistry.googleapis.com]
```

The owner has granted me Cloud Functions Admin, Firebase Admin and Service Account User roles, which is sufficient according to the Firebase Support representative.

I have tried logging in/out, reinstalling Firebase command line tools via `npm install -g firebase-tools`, rerunning `firebase init`.
But I still receive the same error.

Does anyone have any experience with this particular error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution and I'm now able to deploy. Here's the answer that worked for me.

As I mentioned in my question, enabling Cloud Functions Admin, Firebase Admin and Service Account User roles did not fix the problem. So I asked the owner to give me the API Keys Admin role.

Also, I noticed the Artefact Registry API was not enabled at https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/artifactregistry.googleapis.com

Since the error was `Permission denied to enable service [artifactregistry.googleapis.com]`, I asked the owner to enable it manually.

Doing these two things solved the problem, and I am now able to deploy cloud functions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/ and in your project search for the github-action serviceaccount (github-action-xxxxxxxx@YOURPROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com?)

Then add the permission: Artifact Registry Admin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I had a pending payment of $2, I paid and solved the problem. I was able to update my function and deploy my function